# How to use the @ character as a password in WSO2 API Manager 4.0.0?

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am currently using the latest version of WSO2 APIM(4.0.0).

I tried connecting to the ldap as a readonly userstore as per the documentation, but once I startup the server a JMS error occurs possibly due to the @ character used in the password.

Is it possible to use the @ character without breaking WSO2 APIM functionality?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to use @ in JMS connection string. Please check - https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/security/logins-and-passwords/maintaining-logins-and-passwords/#change-the-super-admin-credentials

Comment: Thanks @Pubci for your answer. I referred to the documentation link that you shared and passing the password containing the @ character as <![CDATA[your-password]]> worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me.
In deployment.conf file configure the password with the special character as below.

```
[super_admin]
username = "your-name"
password = "<![CDATA[your-password]]>" 

[apim.throttling.jms]
username = "your-name"
password = "<![CDATA[your-password]]>"
```

Thanks @Pubci for referring the relevant documentation link.